# If $X$ is a compact $n$-manifold then so is $X/G$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In Kosniowski's "A first course in algebraic topology" exercise 11.2(e), we are asked:

> Let $X$ be a $G$-space where $G$ is a finite group that acts freely on $X$. Prove that if $X$ is a compact $n$-manifold then so is $X/G$.

Here $X/G$ is the set of orbits with the quotient topology, and $G$ acts freely means that $g\cdot x\neq x$ if $g\neq id$. The projection $\pi : X\to X/G$ is a closed mapping (since $G$ finite), and $X$ is compact Hausdorff, so $X/G$ is compact Hausdorff.

It remains to select a neighborhood of $U([x])\subset X/G$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. I understand that the idea is to find a neighborhood $U(x)$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is small enough so if $y\in U(x)$ then $g\cdot y\not\in U(x) $ if $g\neq id$; this would give a simple bijection between $U(x)$ and $U([x])=\pi(U(x))$, so that these spaces are homeomorphic. I don't see how to accomplish this using $g$ acts as a homeomorphism on $X$ and that $g$ acts freely.

Comment: It follows from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1495190/724407) that the neighborhood you are trying to find exists. It shows that $G$ is finite and acts freely on a Hausdorff space implies that the action is discontinuous.

Comment: @Kevin.S Thanks for the link, this answers my question!